# how to return array without type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have unit test and i want to return the values like below :

```
(13) [{…}]
0:
id: 154
portfolioCompanyId: 916
url: "https://sharepoint.warburgpincus.com/docs/enterprise/Historical Valuations Documents/Mercator"
dealCode: null
modifiedOn: "2018-09-21T14:55:49.173"
modifiedBy: "setup"
createdOn: "2018-09-21T14:55:49.173"
createdBy: "setup"
linkId: 1
link:
id: 1
name: "Historical Reports"
```

I have written the code which is returning the value like this :

```
[PortfolioCompanyLink]
0: PortfolioCompanyLink
url: "http://google.com"
link: Link
name: "test"
```

I have written the below code

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PortfolioCompanyLinkDropdownComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.portfolioCompany = new PortfolioCompany();
        component.portfolioCompany.name = "Test Company";
        let testLinks = new Array<PortfolioCompanyLink>();
        let testFirstLink = new PortfolioCompanyLink();
        testFirstLink.url = "http://google.com";
        //testFirstLink.linkName="test";
        testFirstLink.link = new Link();
        testFirstLink.link.name = "test";
        testLinks.push(testFirstLink);
        component.portfolioCompany.portfolioCompanyLink = testLinks;

        fixture.detectChanges();
```

when i add

```
console.info(this.portfolioCompany.portfolioCompanyLink)
    .filter(link => link.link.name.toLowerCase()); // it throws an error
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create array without Type, you can use `Array.from()`:

```
let arrayWithoutType =  Array.from(console.info(this.portfolioCompany.portfolioCompanyLink)
                                      .filter(link => link.link.name.toLowerCase()));
```

An example:

```js
console.log(typeof Array.from([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: i dont want to edit the main code. I want to edit the testing code